# SQL when two column's row are same and other column's row is different

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table which I am trying to filter out on a weird method. This is the table I have

```
  PHONE      EFFDATE     ENDDATE
6093852442  8/15/2007   2/2/2008 23:59
**6093852442    5/9/2008    7/14/2009 23:59
6093852442  5/9/2008    12/31/2099**
5745378900  4/10/2012   5/21/2012 23:59
5745378900  2/4/2016    12/31/2099
7173643250  3/24/2008   3/21/2013 23:59
7173643250  3/22/2013   12/31/2099
**3097402606    12/4/2007   1/23/2011 23:59
3097402606  12/4/2007   12/31/2099**
```

Whenever Phone and EFFDATE are same and ENDDATE has different values, it gives me only this data as follows:

```
      PHONE      EFFDATE     ENDDATE
    6093852442  5/9/2008    7/14/2009 23:59
    6093852442  5/9/2008    12/31/2099
    3097402606  12/4/2007   1/23/2011 23:59
    3097402606  12/4/2007   12/31/2099
```

Please let me know how I can do it. Thank you

Comment: Phone and EFFDATE are same??????

Comment: what is your select?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT   phone,
         effdate,
         enddate
FROM     my_table table1
WHERE    EXISTS (SELECT *
                 FROM   my_table table2
                 WHERE  table1.phone = table2.phone
                   AND  table1.effdate = table2.effdate
                   AND  table1.enddate <> table2.enddate)
ORDER BY phone,
         effdate,
         enddate;
```

I suppose the `**` characters are there only to indicate which elements should be shown within the output.

Comment: I was trying to do it bold but it gave me those **